# How to cover exceptions in Visual Studio Code Coverage

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I am new to code-coverage, and I am trying to get my unit tests to cover %100 of my code.

My first question is, is this possible/feasible?

My second, more specific question is, I have the following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears frames, control groups, display groups
/// </summary>
public bool Clear()
{
    try
    {
        this.Frames.Clear();
        this.ControlGroups.Clear();
        this.DisplayGroups.Clear();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Milltown.MTCore.mtException mtEx = new Milltown.MTCore.mtException((int)PFExceptions.Exception_Hidden_FuctionLevel, ex,
        PFCommonVariables.ApplicationPlatform, PFCommonVariables.ApplicationDataSource, "PFSystem:Clear");
        return false;
    }

}
```

My unit test for this method is:

```
//System Clear Test
Assert.IsTrue(MySystem.Clear());
Assert.AreEqual(0,MySystem.Frames.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(0,MySystem.ControlGroups.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(0, MySystem.DisplayGroups.Count);
```

Code coverage shows  that I am covering the lines inside the try block, but not the catch block. How can I cover the code in catch blocks?

Comment: Did you intend to do something with the `mtException`? Just creating an exception doesn't cause it to be thrown, or logged, or anything else.

Comment: 100% code coverage, while a worthy goal, can quickly become counter productive as the closer you get, say around 80-90%, the amount of test code and target churn zip on by the point of diminishing returns. At some point you have to say good enough is good enough. TMMV

Comment: @John Saunders: You assume (perhaps rightly) that mtException is an instance of Exception.

Comment: The mtException is a framework that I am using which logs exceptions into an EventLog. Unfortunately, as of now, I do not have a good method of testing it. Any ideas? It helps not to throw exceptions but to log them to create a better user experience.

Comment: @sbenderli: it's extremely poor practice, and I was trying to give you the benefit of the doubt that your real code actually threw that exception. Pretending an exception didn't happen is a great way to screw up your system. Are you sure all your callers test for the method returning false? Let one miss that check, and you'll wish you'd let the exception propagate. Also, you'd do better with an explicit "LogException" method than with putting the logging functionality into a constructor that constructs an instance yuo don't ever use.

Comment: @John Saunders: I will look into improving this mechanism, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving your coverage is a good goal.  Don't get too focused on the 100% number: it can be very misleading.  More coverage is better than less, but even at 100%, you could be missing many aspects of your code (see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/flaws_in_coverage_measurement.html for examples in Python).  And the last 5% of coverage may not tell you as much as you would like.

As for your exceptions, you'll need a way to force an exception to be thrown from one of your methods.  A common way to do this is to mock out the implementation so you can decide what the sub-objects will actually do during the test, without being tied to a particular implementation.

Comment: ++ agreed. blindly pursuing 100% coverage can result in hairy palms and an acetominphen habit. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, it is feasible. It is also very hard to accomplish, and not everyone is sure that the benefits outweigh the costs.

In regards to achieving your specific goal - look at the [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx), and in your test setup the objects to throw these exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into using the ExpectedExceptionAttribute.